# how to traits default_constructor is private

Tags: c++, type-traits

how to write a type traits function like "is_private_constructor" 
to traits a default constructor of class is private (A class can instantiation) ?

Answer (score 0):

With C++11, just spell it differently: `std::is_default_constructible<Ty>` is defined in the header `<type_traits>`.